# StackOverflow in android choreographer - weird drawable error

Tags: android, debugging, drawable, stack-overflow

I don't know how to debug or solve this problem.

I have a touch handler for a ribbon that changes an image using a TransitionDrawable. If I move the finger very fast for a -moderate long- while, the app crashes with the stack overflow error you can see in the attached stack trace.

```
W/dalvikvm(15391): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c07ac8)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15391): java.lang.StackOverflowError
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.reapplyPadding(LayerDrawable.java:543)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getPadding(LayerDrawable.java:368)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.reapplyPadding(LayerDrawable.java:543)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getPadding(LayerDrawable.java:368)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.reapplyPadding(LayerDrawable.java:543)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getPadding(LayerDrawable.java:368)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.reapplyPadding(LayerDrawable.java:543)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getPadding(LayerDrawable.java:368)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.reapplyPadding(LayerDrawable.java:543)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getPadding(LayerDrawable.java:368)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.reapplyPadding(LayerDrawable.java:543)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.getPadding(LayerDrawable.java:368)
E/AndroidRuntime(15391):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.reapplyPadding(LayerDrawable.java:543)
```

I've managed to enter the debugger just where the app crashes, something that's not very easy, because most of the times it crashes in the choreographer.

The problem is, I don't see anything strange. The routine that causes the problem is the following; that routine is called with a drawable and it builds a Transitiondrawable to show it. Mind that it only crashes when stressing it a lot, ie. moving the finger very fast. I suspect it's related to transitiondrawables being killed before they finish, but it's a really blind shot. When it crashes, the drawables seem OK, ie. not null, coherent dimensions, etc.

```
public static void transitionToBackground(View root, Drawable newBG){
    if (root!=null) {
        Drawable currentBG = root.getBackground();
        if (newBG==currentBG) {
            Log.v(TAG, "*** Same drawables, skipping transition");
            return;
        }

        TransitionDrawable transitionDrawable = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]{currentBG, newBG});
        transitionDrawable.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);

        // next line triggers the disaster
        root.setBackground(transitionDrawable);

        transitionDrawable.startTransition(TRANSITION_SPEED);
    }
}
```

Those are debugger snapshots just when all crashes. They show the infinite loop related to a requestlayout issued if the padding changes, something I don't do!

[image]

[image: debugger view]

Anybody has an idea? Thanks in advance. Please don't hesitate in asking me for more screenshots or additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was relatively simple! Hope I can help a desperate soul sometime in the future.

The problem was, the routine `transitionToBackground` when called repeatedly, incorrectly created a transition between the old `TransitionDrawable` still in progress and a new `BitmapDrawable`. The correct behavior would involve the old BitmapDrawable and a new one.

What happened is, moving the finger fast enough, it was possible to create a `TransitionDrawable` involving the same `TransitionDrawable` itself -a transition in progress- hence the stackoverflow when calling any drawable function like `getMeasuredHeight`, `getPadding`, etc.

To solve it, I just changed the line

```
Drawable currentBG = root.getBackground();
```

for

```
Drawable currentBG = root.getBackground();
if (currentBG instanceof TransitionDrawable) currentBG=((TransitionDrawable)currentBG).getDrawable(1);
```

And it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this `java.lang.StackOverflowError` by doing this :

```
BitmapDrawable next = new BitmapDrawable(result);
Drawable previous = imageView.getDrawable();

if (previous instanceof TransitionDrawable) {
   previous = ((TransitionDrawable) previous).getDrawable(1);
}

if (previous == null) {
   imageView.setImageDrawable(next);
}
else {
    TransitionDrawable transition = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {previous, next});
    imageView.setImageDrawable(transition);
    transition.startTransition(1000);
}
```

Source:
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable

Comment: hey @thiagolr thanks for the answer, looks like we did the same thing, look at my solution below. This was a weird problem but when I figured out what was going on, it became obvious why Android was going nuts.